# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String' error

Tags: c#

I keep on getting this error. This error gets when it goes into the while loop at the invoiceNum variable. Could you please advise what I am doing wrong?

```
    string selectSqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Invoice"; //WHERE invoice_no=" + 1 + "";
               //Create a command in C# to perform the sql Query
               SqlCommand mySelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectSqlQuery, myDBconnection);
               //Creating the process for performing the command
               SqlDataReader performCommand = mySelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
               //Executing the command or running the command
             //  performCommand.Read();

               while (performCommand.Read())
               {

                   invoiceNum = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(0));
                   pcBarcode = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(1));
                   customerID = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(2));
                   probDescr = performCommand.GetString(3);
                   empID = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(4));
                   currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(performCommand.GetString(5));
                   solution = performCommand.GetString(6); ;
                   partsID = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(7));
                   labourPrice = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(8));
                   totalPrice = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(9));
                  // invoiceClass = new Invoice(invoiceNum, pcBarcode, customerID, probDescr, empID, currentDate, solution, partsID, labourPrice, totalPrice);
                }
               //Closing the execution of the command
               performCommand.Close();
               //Closing the connection
               myDBconnection.Close();
           }
```

Comment: What's the invoiceNum variable definition and first column in the Invoice table definition?

Comment: both is of type int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line with invoiceNum to:

```
invoiceNum = performCommand.GetInt16(0);
```

Comment: I get this error: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: it worked when I changed it to invoiceNum = performCommand.GetInt32(0);Yor been struggling for 2 hours with this..Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

To fix such error you must call `ToString` method for your integer :

```
int i = 0;
string s = i.ToString();
```

Also, if your type implements `IConvertible` you can do the following :

```
int i = 0;
string s = Convert.ToString(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `invoiceNum` is a 32-bit integer so you have to read it like one using the reader's [`GetInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The reader does not do automatic translation between types. `GetString` will work only if the underlying field is typed as text and the casting error you're experiencing is exactly telling you that: cannot convert the integer to a string. See the remarks section of [`GetString` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/007ek5d0(v=vs.110).aspx) that says:

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.
>
> Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method.

You should re-write the line:

```
invoiceNum = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetString(0));
```

to instead read:

```
invoiceNum = Convert.ToInt16(performCommand.GetInt32(0));
```

You should review the remaining field-reading lines based on the correct underlying types.

If you want to keep most of your code the same, you should instead use [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04t9z13x(v=vs.110).aspx) because that returns an `object` whose run-time type will reflect the field's type. You can then send that to one of the `Convert` methods (as you have now) and it will do the conversion assuming it supports one between the source and requested type. So just change all your `GetString` calls on the reader to `GetValue`.